# iOS: This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores => How to check if the sqlite database in the app correspond to the model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I would like to check if an old sqlite is present in the app and doesn't match to the new model. For example if I added some tables in the coredata model, I would like to avoid a crash if the app sqlite database doesn't match.

The goal is to delete the data base, and let coredata create another database with the good model.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (schema mismatch or migration failure).  It cannot perform a save operation.'  

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010daed1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c6c1031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreData                            0x000000010d5cc6c3 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _coordinator_you_never_successfully_opened_the_database_schema_mismatch:] + 51
    3   CoreData                            0x000000010d5ccd55 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _introspectLastErrorAndThrow] + 165
    4   CoreData                            0x000000010d5cd101 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 593
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010d5c57a8 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 360
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010d4cbc02 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 642
    7   CoreData                            0x000000010d4cbc2b -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 683
    8   CoreData                            0x000000010d4f469b -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1579
    9   Formbox_Webbox                      0x000000010b853aaf -[DB_ListOfValue_manage removeLinesInTable:] + 1055
    10  Formbox_Webbox                      0x000000010b850add -[DB_ListOfValue_manage removeAllDB] + 2125
    11  Formbox_Webbox                      0x000000010b79d99d -[ViewController sync:] + 141
    12  Formbox_Webbox                      0x000000010b7a0080 __35-[ViewController checkFirstSynchro]_block_invoke + 128
    13  Formbox_Webbox                      0x000000010b83da0a __63+[Reachability checkInternetConnectivityWithSuccessCompletion:]_block_invoke + 346
    14  CFNetwork                           0x0000000113178f4f __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 161
    15  Foundation                          0x000000010c0d7363 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    16  Foundation                          0x000000010c0d71ca -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
    17  Foundation                          0x000000010c0d56b2 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 766
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128dc7ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128e1db8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128dc7ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128e1db8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128e1b48 dispatch_block_perform + 109
    23  Foundation                          0x000000010c0d175b __NSOQSchedule_f + 337
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128dc7ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128e2ad9 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 967
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128e0f54 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 780
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128e836c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
    28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001128e8076 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
    29  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000112dc4169 _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    30  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000112dc3be9 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question. I think a better approach is to use lightweight migrations. Then  create a new version of your data model whenever you change it. Core Data will seamlessly migrate your data into the new model. As a bonus, you don't lose data. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html